# Getting blobs from azure container using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure

I wrote a python script to get all blobs in container from Azure storage account.

def single_value(account,key):

```
blob_service =  BlobService(account_name=account, account_key=key)
next_marker = None
while True:
    file = open('%s.txt'%(account), 'a')
    blobs = blob_service.list_blobs('containername', marker=next_marker)
    next_marker = blobs.next_marker
    try:
       file.write("%s"%blob.name)
       file.write('\n')
       file.close()
       print(len(blobs))
       if not next_marker:
           break
    except Exception as e:
        print('failed to complete the check: {0}'.format(e))
```

single_value('storageaccount', 'key')

When I execute the script I am getting error

```
azure.common.AzureHttpError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

I couldn't figure out the issue.

if I don't use function I am able to get retrieve blobs

Comment: Did you try this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage/#list-the-blobs-in-a-container?

Comment: @ David: Yes I have tried.  Is there is any api call to get size of the blob?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179394.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the documentation. It really helped